# How to assert Array element via cypress dynamicly

Tags: javascript, cypress

My question is about the verification of Array elements dynamically. In my project, I have to suggest a price, and every time this suggested price will increase I need such a script that will verify all these elements dynamically.
In Screenshot I tried to show what I need to verify. I used below script:

```
    ` describe('POST method', () => {
    it('suggest a price', () => {
     //Suggest a price you are willing to pay. Available only for auctionType: fixed_price

        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url:"xxxxxx",

            headers:{
                "Authorization":"LOOL",
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },

            body: {
                "id": "d42f516a867590633dd8a82cb2563437",
                "bid": 6900,
                "auctionPlatformId": "xxx",
                "auctionPlatformUserId": 0
            },

            failOnStatusCode: false

            
        })


expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
      expect(res.body).to.have.property("id", "d42f516a867590633dd8a82cb2563437")
      expect(res.body).to.have.property("amount", 6900)
      expect(res.body).to.have.property("auctionPlatformId", "abc")
     expect(res.body).to.have.property("auctionPlatformId", 0)`
```

but this code is not dynamic and also not verifying

[image: This screen is what I need to make an assertion]

Answer (score 2):

One way is you can use `within` and define the range.

```js
expect(res.body.amount).to.be.within(6000,7000)
```

To generate random values for bid you can use `Math.random`

```js
"bid": Math.floor( Math.random() * 10000 ) + 1  //Generate random numbers between 1 and 10000
```

So Assuming that in your response all amounts are less than or equal to the bid amount you input, you can do something like this. So You decide the min and max values for your random bid amount and then using the same(min and max values), you can assert that the numbers in response body are within this range.

```js
describe("POST method", () => {
  it("suggest a price", () => {
    //Suggest a price you are willing to pay. Available only for auctionType: fixed_price
    var minval = 1
    var maxval = 10000
    var bidAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxval) + minval
    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "xxxxxx",

      headers: {
        Authorization: "LOOL",
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },

      body: {
        id: "d42f516a867590633dd8a82cb2563437",
        bid: bidAmount,
        auctionPlatformId: "xxx",
        auctionPlatformUserId: 0,
      },

      failOnStatusCode: false,
    }).then((res) => {
      expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
      //If you want to assert separately
      expect(res.body.suggestedPrices[0].amount).to.be.within(minval, maxval)
      expect(res.body.suggestedPrices[1].amount).to.be.within(minval, maxval)
      expect(res.body.suggestedPrices[2].amount).to.be.within(minval, maxval)

      //If you want to assert all together
      for (var index in res.body.suggestedPrices) {
        expect(res.body.suggestedPrices[index].amount).to.be.within(
          minval,
          maxval
        )
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: but this amount can be 80,0000 as well:)

Comment: You can play around with the range. Can you add the entire test ?

Comment: In request body I requested amount by my own.

Comment: yies I am adding.

Comment: I also need to put my request body amount Dynamic. I donno how

Comment: How is the amount in response body appear if you give eg.8000. Is there any particular way the numbers in the response body are calculated or they are random ?

Comment: I can give random number

Comment: To automatically generate random numbers you can use `Math.random`. updated in the answer

Comment: but how toadjust this one:  expect(res.body.amount).to.be.within(6000,7000)

Comment: Thank you so much! really appriciated!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: I have one more question (if I can ask..)
I need to randomly bid the amount in a way that it will be incremented by 100.




var minval = 1;
var maxval = 1000000;
var bidAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxval) + minval; - How can I make this logic here.

This is error I get when I bid randomly:  
Bids should be incremented by 100, input was 589